# Xpages getting field value knowing the UNID of the document

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs, ssjs

Is there a way I can get the field value of a document if I know the document UNID?

I have the following code:

```
var a = database.getDocumentByUNID(sessionScope.unid);
```

- sessionScope.unid contains the documentUNID.

I can't see any methods avaible if I do `a.` . Is there something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SSJS does not provide typeahead unless you specifically cast variables as the class you wish to use. So to get typeahead you need to use:

```
var a:NotesDocument = database.getDocumentByUNID(sessionScope.unid);
```